# Qt Designer 5 and pyuic5 place import statement incorrectly for promoted widgets

Tags: python, qt, qt-designer, pyqt5, pyuic

I'm using pyQt5 together with Qt Designer (v 5.2.1) and pyuic5 (v 5.2.1) to create a GUI.  I've run into a snag: when attempting to use a custom widget via promoting the widget like so:

[image: Promoting a QWidget to Ui_ACS_AlertLightStrip]

everything generates as expected, except that the resulting import statement, which itself looks correct:

```
from acs_dashboards.lib.acs_general_gui import Ui_ACS_AlertLightStrip
```

ends up at the BOTTOM of the generated python file after running pyuic5.  Obviously this causes the generated references to Ui_ACS_AlertLightStrip to throw:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Ui_ACS_AlertLightStrip'

I've hunted the web and can't find anybody who's had a similar problem with Qt Designer or pyuic5.  Most references are for pyqt4 and before and promoting widgets in this fashion seems to work fine with that version.

Anybody seen this before and have a remedy?

Comment: Why do you say "obviously"? What evidence do you have that it causes the `ImportError`? Are you claiming that editing the generated module and moving the statement to the top fixes the problem? Maybe you should check that the import path has been specified correctly, instead.

Comment: Agreed. Import errors are raised when an import statement is reached, but the module/file can't be found, not when you try and use a class before it has been imported.